# invalid username and password snowsql

Tags: snowsql

While login to snowflake from command prompt I'm getting the below error

the error:

> 250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB:
>   EGA12345.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443. Incorrect username or
>   password was specified. If the error message is unclear, enable
>   logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the
>   cause. Contact support for further help.

I can able to log into web UI by using the same username and password, but not from snowsql
command is `snowsql -a EGA12345.us-east-1 -u venu`

thanks in advance.

Venu

Answer (score 1):

My password had a lot of special characters in it, it didn't work in either the config or the command line. I had to add it to the config wrapped in double quotes (") for it to work.

Example:
"password!@#%@#$@%^T*(&^"

Answer (score 0):

Check what role you're using via snowsql. The default role would be "defaultrolename", which I doubt exists for your account. I tested this by changing the .snowsql/config file to have a connection where rolename=non-existing-role. Using that connection, I get the error in your original post.